# Powershell 7 - Cannot closing parent folder via Close-SMBOpenfile

Tags: powershell

I have been closing open network files via below powershell script. it works for subfolders and files. But , it not closing parent folder like below output. (D:\TEST)

Here is my script:

```
Get-SMBOpenFile | where {$_.Path -like "D:\TEST\*" -or $_.Path -like "D:\TEST\"} | Close-SmbOpenFile -Force -Verbose
```

Output :

```
FileId       SessionId    Path                     ShareRelativePath ClientComputerName ClientUserName 
------       ---------    ----                     ----------------- ------------------ -------------- 
618475292929 618475290673 D:\TEST\                   192.168.1.1       CONTOSO\user1
```

EDIT :

```
Get-SMBOpenFile | where {$_.Path -like "D:\TEST\*"}

FileId       SessionId    Path                                          ShareRelativePath     ClientComputerName ClientUserName
------       ---------    ----                                          -----------------     ------------------ --------------
619012162101 618475290673 D:\TEST\New folder - Copy                    New folder - Copy     192.168.1.1       CONTOSO\User
619012162273 618475290673 D:\TEST\                                                           192.168.1.1       CONTOSO\User
619012162277 618475290673 D:\TEST\New folder - Copy (2)                 New folder - Copy (2) 192.168.1.1       CONTOSO\User
```

Then ,

```
Get-SMBOpenFile | where {$_.Path -like "D:\TEST\*"} | Close-SmbOpenFile -Force -Verbose
```

As result,

```
Get-SMBOpenFile | where {$_.Path -like "D:\TEST\*"}

FileId       SessionId    Path                     ShareRelativePath ClientComputerName ClientUserName
------       ---------    ----                     ----------------- ------------------ --------------
619012162357 618475290673 D:\TEST\                                   192.168.1.1       CONTOSO\User
619012162365 618475290673 D:\TEST\                                   192.168.1.1       CONTOSO\User
```

Comment: So you get no error message and the output you're showing is what you get when you run `Get-SmbOpenFile` _again_, afterwards?

Comment: I've updated my results. Even though I close it , as you can see its returning two results. btw , there is no any error message. Actually , powershell command is works very well. is it expected behaviour ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your symptom on my W11 22H2 machine.  I wouldn't expect `Close-SmbFile` to ever produce (data) output, and I personally haven't seen it (perhaps that's not what's happening for you, but your post at least in part still suggests that).

Comment: @mklement0   Hi ,  Actually , I have similar issue such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780276/windows-can-not-force-close-network-file-handle-can-not-close-system-pid-4